# How to propagate a Task's Canceled status to a continuation task

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am using the Task Parallel Library in my application.  I have a Task (let's call it "DoSomething") which may be canceled.  Whether the task is faulted, canceled, or completes successfully, I have a continuation attached to that task which performs some cleanup.

In the code that launches this task, I want to return a Task object whose status (faulted, canceled, ran to completion) reflects the status of the DoSomething task, however it's important that this task I return not reflect this status until the continuation task executes.

Here's an example:

```
public Task Start(CancellationToken token)
{
    var doSomethingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomething
                                                , token);

    var continuationTask = doSomethingTask.ContinueWith
                (
                 (antecedent) =>
                     {
                         if (antecedent.IsFaulted || antecedent.IsCanceled)
                         {
                             //Do failure-specific cleanup
                         }

   //Do general cleanup without regard to failure or success
                      }
                 );

//TODO: How do I return a Task obj which Status reflect the status of doSomethingTask,
//but will not transition to that status until continuationTask completes?
}
```

I could use a TaskCompletionSource, but that seems kludgy.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Posted an answer, but there was a hitch.  Working on a more correct solution, which I should have shortly.

Comment: Alright... question time:  Do you need to Wait() on the returned Task?

Comment: Yes.  The returned task needs to reflect the status of the original task, which includes blocking until that task completes execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `TaskCompletionSource` is actually ideal for this scenario. I.e. you are trying to return a `Task` as a signal of completion of your work, but manually control when and how that task reports its status. You could easily hide the boiler plate required for this with an extension method like this:

```
public static Task<T> WithCleanup<T>(this Task<T> t, Action<Task<T>> cleanup) {
    var cleanupTask = t.ContinueWith(cleanup);
    var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    cleanupTask.ContinueWith(_ => {
        if(t.IsCanceled) {
            completion.SetCanceled();
        } else if(t.IsFaulted) {
            completion.SetException(t.Exception);
        } else {
            completion.SetResult(t.Result);
        }
    });
    return completion.Task;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var doSomethingTask = Task.Factory
  .StartNew<object>(DoSomething, token)
  .WithCleanup(Cleanup);
```

The only real caveat is that you can't do this with plain old `Task` since there is no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: You can use generic TCS for the non-generic case, since `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`.