# How to execute async operations sequentially?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Now I am using something simmilar to this construction

```
A.Completed += () =>
{ B.Completed += () =>
  {  C.Completed += () =>
     {
       //
     }
     C();
   }
   B();
 }  
 A();
```

And not very happy with it. Is there a better, more cleaner way to do such kind of sequent/concurrent action execution?

I have a look at Rx framework, but it is designed for other tasks and looks like way overkill for my problem.

Comment: you may also check out the signalR source code for stuff like Then, Catch fluent use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/). It's based on Rx and will simplify your code a lot. Here is an example: [Calling Web Services in Silverlight using ReactiveXaml](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/09/26/calling-web-services-in-silverlight-using-reactivexaml/)

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to nest setting up the Completed events, unless someone might actually call B or C before A is completed.  If you separate it out, here is what it looks like:

```
A.Completed += () => { B(); };
B.Completed += () => { C(); };  
C.Completed += () => { //   }; 

A();
```

I think removing the nesting actually makes it much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at TPL. You can write code like in this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799011/how-to-propagate-a-tasks-canceled-status-to-a-continuation-task)

Answer (score 1):

It's not *much* cleaner, but you might have a look at `BackgroundWorker`.

```
BackgroundWorker A = new BackgroundWorker();
A.DoWork += (s, e) => AMethod();
A.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => BMethod();

BackgroundWorker B = new BackgroundWorker();
B.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => CMethod();

//etc
```

You're not really cutting down on the code too much, but I'd say it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: Be very careful with this.  I typically recommend avoiding threads to handle async program flow.  There are better constructs than threads for organizing the code.  The complexity in both code readability and execution my not be worth it.

Comment: What constructs are there that you recommend??

Answer (score 1):

Wait for C# 5.0 and use the new `async` and `await` keywords.

Here are a few preliminary links about this:

- [“Simplifying Asynchrony – That for which we await”, Reed Copsey, Jr.](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/10/28/c-5-async-part-1-simplifying-asynchrony-that-for-which-we-await/)
- [“C# Async”, csharphelp.com](http://www.csharphelp.com/2011/01/c-async/)
- [“Initial thoughts on C# 5's async support”, John Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/29/initial-thoughts-on-c-5-s-async-support.aspx)

Comment: Have the same filling. Any implementation with current language posibilities obscure the code. Hope that the C# 5 will be released soon.

Comment: In the mean time, this isn't a serious answer.